# Наследование C#. Замена множественного наследования

Tags: c#, наследование

У меня есть класс `Client`, от которого наследуют два класса - `Writer` и `Reviewer`. В свою очередь, оба класса-наследника должны отправлять запросы на сервер. Для работы с запросами есть класс `Requests`. Вопрос - как обеспечить доступ из класса`Requests` к членам обоих классов - `Writer` и `Reviewer`, ведь в C# множественное наследование отсутствует? Может с помощью интерфейсов, но как?

Comment: А где тут множественное? Из описания следует, что у Writer и Reviewer по одному базовому классу Client. Может подразумевалось обратное?

Comment: имеется ввиду, что и Writer, и Reviewer должны посылать запросы на сервер. Большая часть этих запросов похожа и содержит поля обоих этих классов, поэтому хотелось бы, чтобы Request наследовал и от Writer, и от Reviewer

Comment: Вот теперь совсем непонятно стало. Кто кого наследует? И кто что делает и через кого?

Comment: используйте внедряемую зависимость через конструктор и передайте класс Requests в оба класса. в Client укажите, что это свойство должно быть реализовано наследниками.

Comment: у вас вопрос по коду, вот и покажите код. Не надо рассказывать что у вас в коде есть, это бесполезное занятие - вы же ответ для конкретного кода хотите получить, а не для того кода, который вы сначала текстом описали а потом мы все дружно представили.